# mysql select dummy record when JOIN condition not met

Tags: mysql, join, dummy-data

I have two tables, one a record of hits, the other a user table. If as user is logged in, the hit is recorded with that user's ID. If the user is not logged in, the hit is logged as `user_id = 0`

When I run a report, I want to JOIN the hits against the users table to get the username-- but there's no user with the ID 0, so I get bad data back (eg. no results for all the non-logged in hits). Is there a way to select a dummy username like "Guest" where the JOIN condition isn't met?

Here's the query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(a.timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d') date, count(a.*) hits, a.user_id, b.username
FROM hits a
JOIN users b ON a.user_id = b.id
WHERE 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try left join and COALESCE to default

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(a.timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d') date, count(a.*) hits, a.user_id,
  COALESCE( b.username, 'GUEST')
FROM hits a
LEFT JOIN USERS b ON a.user_id = b.id
```

Comment: @julio. No problem you can also use [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) instead

Answer (score 0):

You need to do an LEFT OUTER JOIN; that will return you the records that have a user_id entry in the hits table where the user does not exist in the users table.